# Cordova Javascript Worker issue on iOS 14 : SecurityError : The operation is insecure

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, webkit, web-worker

I had the web Worker working perfectly in my Cordova application on Android devices and iOS 13 but after upgrade to iOS 14.3, I am getting the exception "SecurityError: The operation is insecure".

Here is a snippet of the service worker call:

```
try{
    workerDB = new Worker("js/worker.js");
}catch(ex){
    alert(ex);
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In order to access `file://` you need to add the following two elements in your config.xml.

```xml
<preference name="scheme" value="app" />
<preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
```

Read more [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/883#issuecomment-643657781)